# Is it possible to run nodemon to restart server upon changes on front-end?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemon

I'm rather new to this area, so please excuse if this question is completely basic. I've seen some tutorials use nodemon to watch files, and restart servers on Nodejs backend. I've seen others use webpack to watch files such as `create react app` on frontend. Can you actually use nodemon to watch files and refresh pages on the front end?

Answer (score 2):

Yes I believe you can set it up with your `package.json` scripts!
For instance with a node server with a `create-react-app` within a client folder you could declare a start script along the lines of:

```
"start": "concurrently \"nodemon server.js\" \"cd client && nodemon start\""
```

Then when you run `npm start` this will run `nodemon` on both the server file and the client folder

Just be aware this assumes your server file is named `server.js` and your client files are in a folder named `client` and will require you to have the `concurrently` dependency installed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this one if you already have `create react app` within a client folder.
`"server": "nodemon server.js",
 "client": "cd client && yarn start",
 "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""`

Concurrently allows us to run both on one terminal as well as it allows us to pass `--kill-others-on-fail` which means that if one breaks (control + c on mac), the other one will also break

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon is primarily used for backend development with Node.js, as it monitors changes in server-side files and automatically restarts the server when changes are made. However, it is possible to use Nodemon for frontend development as well, especially in cases where you are using a tool like Webpack to build and bundle your frontend assets.

For example, if you have a frontend project that uses Webpack to compile your JavaScript, CSS, and HTML files, you can use Nodemon to monitor changes in your source files and automatically trigger a rebuild of your project whenever changes are detected. This can save you time and make your frontend development workflow more efficient.

That being said, Nodemon is not a frontend-specific tool, and there may be other tools and frameworks that are better suited for frontend development, depending on your specific needs and requirements.